# How is the samba recycle bin supposed to work with deleted folders?

Tags: samba, smb-conf

vfs object = recycle in smb.cfg works fine for deleted files. 
Yet, how is the samba recycle bin function supposed to work for folders?

I made the following observations:

**with** option **recycle:keeptree = Yes**

1 - delete a file - will move it to the recycle bin, preserving the original folder structure

2 - delete a folder which contains a file - will move it, and the files beneath to the recycle bin, preserving the original folder structure

**3** - delete a folder which contains no files - **folder disappears, nothing in the recycle bin**

**without** option **recycle:keeptree = Yes**

4 - delete a file - will move it to the recycle bin without folder structure

**5** - delete a folder which contains a file - **folder and files disappear, nothing in the recycle bin**

**6** - delete a folder which contains no files - **folder disappears, nothing in the recycle bin**

**Question**: Are cases 3,5 and 6 as per design?

Thanks
Dan

Answer (score 1):

3 and 6 are certainly by design. There is generally no reason to keep track of a no longer needed directory that contains nothing.

I do not believe case 5 is observed correctly. If there was a file there, the file must be in the recycler even without keeping the folder, therefore it may have ended up named or positioned differently and you probably did not notice it.